# Unrecognized expression '$getField'

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to add new field using the value from object:

```
db.requests.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        {
          tag: "prod",
          status: "OK",
          created_at: {
            $gte: ISODate("2021-01-01"),
            $lt: ISODate("2022-01-01")
          }
        },
        
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": { "fields": {"$objectToArray": "$fields"} }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$fields"
  },
  {
    "$addFields": { "fname": {"$getField": { "field": "k", "input": "$fields" }}, <---- HERE
                    "fconf": {"$getField": { "field": "confidence", "input": {"$getField": { "field": "v", "input": "$fields" }}}}
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$document",
      "fname": {"$sum": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {"$gte": [ "$fconf", 0.99 ]},
          "then": 1,
          "else": 0 }
      }},
    }
  }
])
```

But getting error:

```
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "Invalid $addFields :: caused by :: Unrecognized expression '$getField'",
"code" : 168,
"codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator"
```

My mongo version is 5.0.4, `$getField` was introduced in 5.0.0, so what's wrong?

UPDATE:
Sample Data

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("610bcecea7f31aaa40b08186"), "tag" : "prod", "document" : "RUT", "fields" : { "9-1-1-1" : { "text" : "1018462101", "confidence" : 1 }, "9-1-1-2" : { "text" : "32", "confidence" : 1 }, "9-1-1-3" : { "text" : "*******", "confidence" : 0.99 }, "9-1-1-4" : { "text" : "*******", "confidence" : 0.99 }, "9-1-1-5" : { "text" : "*******", "confidence" : 0.99 }, "9-1-1-6" : { "text" : "CATALINA", "confidence" : 0.99 }, "9-1-1-7" : { "text" : "8299", "confidence" : 1 } }, "status" : "OK", "created_at" : ISODate("2021-08-05T11:43:10.110Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("610bced6a7f31aaa40b08187"), "tag" : "prod", "document" : "FNA", "fields" : { "20-20-4-4-1-1-1-1-2-1" : { "text" : "", "confidence" : 0 }, "20-20-4-4-1-1-1-1-3-1" : { "text" : "", "confidence" : 0 }, "20-20-4-4-1-1-1-1-4-1" : { "text" : "", "confidence" : 0 }, "20-20-4-4-1-1-1-1-5-1" : { "text" : "", "confidence" : 0 } }, "status" : "OK", "created_at" : ISODate("2021-08-05T11:43:18.706Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("610bcef70b1451dacf81bf32"), "tag" : "prod", "document" : "TAX", "fields" : { "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-2-1" : { "text" : "6729000", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-3-1" : { "text" : "7443000", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-4-1" : { "text" : "54895000", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-5-1" : { "text" : "16582000", "confidence" : 0.99 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-6-1" : { "text" : "16582000", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-7-1" : { "text" : "36083000", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-8-1" : { "text" : "2000", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-9-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 0.7 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-10-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 0.7 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-11-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-12-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-13-1" : { "text" : "2000", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-14-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-15-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 0.7 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-16-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 0.7 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-17-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-18-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-19-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-20-1" : { "text" : "52667000", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-21-1" : { "text" : "16582000", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-22-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-23-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-24-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-25-1" : { "text" : "36085000", "confidence" : 0.99 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-26-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-27-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-28-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-29-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-30-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 0.7 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-31-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-32-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 0.7 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-33-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-34-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-35-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-36-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-37-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-38-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-39-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-40-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-41-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 1 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-42-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 0.7 }, "20-19-5-1-2-1-1-1-43-1" : { "text" : "0", "confidence" : 1 } }, "status" : "OK", "created_at" : ISODate("2021-08-05T11:43:51.466Z") }
```

Expected result:
I need sth like `{_id: "RUT", fields: {9-1-1-1: 10, 9-1-1-2: 5}}`
So i need to aggregate everything and count each field by name that has confidence more that 0.99. There can be many documents each with different set of fields, I need first to group them by `document`, than count between many documents of this type the procedure that I described above

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and desired result?

Comment: Your query runs without error on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5X9ivm06em8 "Link to working example -->").  Would you verify the version of *both* your client and the server?

Comment: Is this what you want: https://mongoplayground.net/p/2u55ys0g8Id ?

Comment: I think, making the field names non-dynamic would make it much easier.

Comment: @nimrodserok Thanks! That's exactly what I need

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit If that was an option I would've done it already :)

Comment: please check&add result of `db.version()` to be sure. it is possible you are trying your query on an older server without knowing.

Answer (score 0):

After your first three steps, we can use a `$match` before your `$group` which makes things simpler, and move the `$addFields` step after it (here as `$project`). Then it is just a matter of `$group` again and `$project` to get the wanted results:

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        {
          tag: "prod",
          status: "OK",
          created_at: {
            $gte: ISODate("2021-01-01"),
            $lt: ISODate("2022-01-01")
          }
        },
        
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {"fields": {"$objectToArray": "$fields"}}
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$fields"
  },
  {
    $match: {"fields.v.confidence": {$gte: 0.99}}
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        doc: "$document",
        fname: "$fields.k"
      },
      "dataK": {
        $first: "$fields.k"
      },
      "dataV": {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {"data.k": "$dataK", "data.v": "$dataV"}
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.doc",
      fields: {$push: "$data"}
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {"fields": {"$arrayToObject": "$fields"}}
  }
])
```

Can be seen [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dwtas86k6rK) on the playground, with one extra document, demonstrating the count of `fields`.